# self join in sql for generating Rank

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I want to calculate rank of each student according to the marks obtained by him. But if the marks are in -ve value the query doesn't show the appropriate answer.

```
SELECT a1.ResultByTestId, a1.ObtainedMarks, COUNT(a2.ObtainedMarks) Rank
 FROM ResultByTest a1, ResultByTest a2
WHERE a1.ObtainedMarks < a2.ObtainedMarks 
      or 
      (a1.ObtainedMarks=a2.ObtainedMarks and a1.StudentId = a2.StudentId)
GROUP BY  a1.ObtainedMarks, a1.ResultByTestId
ORDER BY a1.ObtainedMarks DESC, Rank DESC
```

and the answer table is :-

```
resutlByTestId  ObtainedMarks  Rank

11                36              1
10                22              2
3                  9              3
9                  7              4
6                  5              5
8                  3              6
7                  2              7
4                  0              8
5                  0              8
1                  0              8
2                  0              8
13                -5              12
```

is there anybody to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [DENSE_RANK() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) in MSSQL 2008:

```
SELECT ResultByTestId, ObtainedMarks, 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (order by ObtainedMarks desc) as Rank
 FROM ResultByTest
ORDER by ObtainedMarks DESC;
```

also here is your query with `COUNT(DISTINCT <>)`:

```
SELECT a1.ResultByTestId, a1.ObtainedMarks, 
 COUNT(DISTINCT a2.ObtainedMarks) Rank
 FROM ResultByTest a1, ResultByTest a2
WHERE a1.ObtainedMarks < a2.ObtainedMarks 
      or 
      (a1.ObtainedMarks=a2.ObtainedMarks and a1.StudentId = a2.StudentId)
GROUP BY  a1.ObtainedMarks, a1.ResultByTestId
ORDER BY a1.ObtainedMarks DESC, Rank DESC
```

Comment: then just change your query `COUNT(DISTINCT a2.ObtainedMarks)`

Comment: thank you so much. but can you please tell me that if i want to calculate the rank by using Rank() function which u suggest me.

Comment: Then use [DENSE_RANK()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) instead of `RANK`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the [Dense_Rank](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) function

```
Select
  StudentID,
  ObtainedMarks,
  Dense_Rank() Over (Order By ObtainedMarks Desc) as Rank
From 
  ResultByTest
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9e5c/1

The reason you would normally use rank, is that when you ask the person who got -5 where did you come they say "9th". Then you ask, how many people beat you "12". And then you look confused.

Answer (score 0):

The Output is correct there is no problem because of the -ve score as four students got 0 and ranked 8th
so
8-8
8-9
8-10
8-11

this is how it will count so the next rank would obviously 12

Comment: yes i know that it is calculating 8 rank 4 time so the next rank is 12, which is creating problem for me, i want rank 9 after 8 not 12.

Answer (score 0):

```
--setup test data

DECLARE @ResultByTest TABLE (ResultByTestId int, ObtainedMarks int)

INSERT INTO @ResultByTest VALUES
(11,                36),
(10,                22),
(3,                  9),
(9,                  7),
(6,                  5),
(8,                  3),
(7,                  2),
(4,                  0),
(5,                  0),
(1,                  0),
(2,                  0),
(13,                -5)

-- this will give you the results you have

select *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ObtainedMarks DESC) AS [Rank]
from @ResultByTest

-- this will give you the results I think you want

select *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ObtainedMarks DESC) AS [Rank]
from @ResultByTest
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DENSE_RANK to get rid of the gaps.

```
DECLARE @ObtainedMarks TABLE (
ResultByTestId INT,
ObtainedMarks INT,
StudentId INT

)

INSERT INTO @ObtainedMarks VALUES
(1,0,1),
(2,0,1),
(3,9,1),
(4,0,1),
(5,0,1),
(6,5,1),
(7,2,1),
(8,3,1),
(9,7,1),
(10,22,1),
(11,36,1),
(13,-5,1)

SELECT 
    ResultByTestId,
    ObtainedMarks,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (order by ObtainedMarks desc) [Rank]
FROM @ObtainedMarks
```